# Windows 10 - Can't enter password for Wi-Fi because it is demanding a Network Security Key

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, router

I have installed the modem to my PC, which is also a Wi-Fi router (TP-LINK modem Wi-Fi N router TD-W8960N). When installing this device on my PC I have assigned a password to it. When I am trying to connect to this Wi-Fi with my Laptop with Windows 10, it is asking for Network Security Key.

Usually it should first ask for a password and I should have a choice to enter the Network Security Key. I don't know how to connect it now. I tried the password that I specified during the installation process. I also tried so called Wireless Password/Pin stated on the bottom of router. Both of them do not work. Can anyone help me to figure it out? How can I get to the point, where I can enter the password that I created? Or how can I connect to Wi-Fi if the Password/Pin stated on the router does not work?

Answer (score 0):

To reset the password for this router take a pen and put it inside this hole below for 30 second hold it until the LED of the router flash
[image]

There is two passwords:

- Password for your wireless network.
- Password to access the administration setting of your router.

**NOTE:** In some routers it will ask you for a PIN key/security key you can find that on the back of your router.